# NoMethodError in Posts#show ;

Tags: rails-migrations

i have been learning rails through

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

I came across a error while performing save data in controller. The error that comes up when running the blog is :-undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

**

> **My code for posts_controller.rb  is**

**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def new
end
def create
@post=Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title,:text))
@post.save
redirect_to @post
end

private
def post_params
params.require(:post).permit(:title,:text)
end

def show
@post=Post.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

**

My code for show.html.rb is

**

```
<p>
<strong> Title:</strong>
<%= @post.title %>
</p>
<p>
<strong> Text:</strong>
<%= @post.text %>
</p>
```

**

> The code for create_posts.rb

**

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

Please help me out why this error is coming up when I have defined title in create_posts.

Comment: Please add output to 'rake routes' command

Comment: can u elaborate your statement..where to add "rake routes" command

Comment: Type 'rake routes' at your terminal - in your project's folder, and add the output to your question.Then it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: C:\Sites\blog>rake routes
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern       Controller#Action
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)  welcome#index
posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
root GET    /                         welcome#index

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mZrqI.png

Comment: I have added image and description of rake routes command ..now can you help me to debug the error

Comment: Your routes seems to be OK. Did you get the error when trying to create an object through the GUI?

Comment: If so, what your 'new' function is empty?

Comment: what should be there in "new" function

Comment: now some other error is coming up ...the error is "Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for PostsController"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All methods defined after `private` are accessible only internally. Move the `show` method above `private`. And make sure you have a file called app/views/posts/show.html.erb and not .rb

Good luck!

Comment: Now you are into views. Make sure you have a file called `app/views/posts/show.html.erb` and not `.rb`.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect the view gotcha also. You are welcome.

Comment: you said to save the file with extension .erb not .rb. what is the difference between the two

Comment: file with extension erb(embedded ruby) allows you put ruby code in html file whereas file with extension rb does not.

Comment: Yes, @vikram is correct. As the missing template warning lists `:handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :builder, :rxml, :erb]`, rails is looking for one of those extensions with the expected name in the views directory. It will also process a plain old .html file. A .erb file is first processed by ruby, and then rendered as an html. A .rb file is pure ruby. Look at controllers, models, and helpers. They are all .rb . I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Make sure that you trying to access show method before the declaration of private as we can't access private methods outside of the class.

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end


def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

//vKj